# Managing the JVM from within the JVM

Tags: java, jvm, java-native-interface, ipc

I need to start multiple JVM processes as subprocesses of a running JVM, and then access fields inside each subprocess (Like a form of IPC). Basically https://npmjs.com/package/java but for Java. I know this is possible using JNI, so my current plan is to use JNI and some native methods, but seeing as it'll be a bit complicated, I wanted to ask and make sure there are no better/easier alternative solutions.

Thanks.

Comment: That sounds like the most difficult way to do Java IPC. Have you considered RMI, REST, a database, sockets and serialised objects...

Comment: Can you give us a broader view of what you are trying to do? Why do you need many JVMs? What are your end goals?

Comment: JNI is an interface between Java code and native code within one JVM. How is that related to your goal of communicating from one JVM to another?

Comment: I want to avoid using traditional IPC methods like REST because this will be starting multiple JVMs and that sounds like port hell, I can't go the serialized object route because I need to call methods on the objects that get sent back/forth. I need to be able to call methods in the target JVM, as well as receive data from them, the easiest way I know of doing this is through JNI, but I also know JNI only lets you start one JVM, so I now doubt that solution would work either. I realize now I started a bit of an XY Problem, I'll explain what I'm trying to achieve in the next comment (char lim).

Comment: Part 2: I'm essentially trying to make a server daemon that can start/communicate with game servers, and matchmake players into servers. I already have a version of this, but it needs a rewrite as it's very inaccurate at times. The daemon needs to be constantly aware of what players are in each server, as well as a few other statistics, currently I achieve this through storing players that get matchmaked on the daemon, but if the game server refuses the connection this gets out of sync, the best solution would be calling the getPlayers method in each target JVM.

Comment: Have you considered having a database of players(like sqllite or something) and have each jvm connect to that database, with the daemon dispatching from the data in the database and the other jvms periodically updating the database?

Comment: Another option is just running everything in one JVM, which may or may not be viable depending on exactly how your game servers work.

Comment: “Calling a method in a different JVM” is just an euphemism for “communicating with a software in the other JVM that will do the call”. All frameworks promising to do remote calls are just encapsulating that principle. So your question is about communication, 1) which method (socket, pipe, shared memory, or proprietary messaging), 2) which protocol or data format, 3) where to draw the line between programming yourself or using existing solutions.

Comment: Holger, The reason I want to do it this way is to avoid things like sockets, I don't want to have to write a ton of boilerplate and serialization (and deal with synchronization issues), my current system works using sockets and redis pub/sub. Just calling the methods in the actual JVM would be so much easier to deal with.

PiRocks, I'm running Minecraft servers, which contain a bunch of static variables, so simply running it in 1 JVM won't work. I did however work on a classloader/agent system that replaces package names and loads multiple servers, but it's sketchy so I'd rather not use it.

Comment: What I tried to say with my previous comment: 1. There is no way around some sort of serializing. You can’t transfer a Java object but only a representation of it. If you don’t use a format automatically generated for your objects by some library but carefully decide what (low level) data to transfer and in which format, you may indeed be more efficient. 2. There is no way around the transfer. Local sockets are not that bad if you cared for the first point. A compact representation fitting into one packet sent via local socket is not different to shared memory. But I named the alternatives.